# nginx vhost a record

Tags: nginx, vhosts, a-records

I've been using nginx with vhosts and have currently 5 config files (addresses are given as examples) in these exact order:

- default
- my website (www.mywebsite.com)
- address given by my web hosting service (myvps.webhoster.com)
- IPv4 address (i.e. : 100.0.0.1)
- IPv6 address (i.e. : 2001::1)

`www.mywebsite.com A record --> 100.0.0.1` &
`www.mywebsite.com AAAA record --> 2001::1`

- When I access my website using IPv4 I get on the vhost config for `100.0.0.1`,
- when I access my website using IPv6 I get on the vhost config for `default`
- when I access directly my IPv6 address I get on the `default` config

Vhost files :

```
# default file :
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    ...
}
# 2nd file :
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    ...
}
# 4th file
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 100.0.0.1;
    ...
}
# 5th file
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name 2001::1;
    ...
}
```

I don't get why it goes to default ...

Comment: I am not an IPv6 expert, but should that server name be `"[2001::1]"`. You might want to see what name your browser places in the `Host` field of the HTTP request header. This is what `nginx` will use to match a `server_name`.

Comment: that corrects my second and last problem but now, when I access my website with IPv4 I get the default config file